# iOS 9.3 final build number

Tags: ios, ios9.3

iOS 9.3 was released on march 21, 2016, and according to its [download page](https://developer.apple.com/ios/download/), this version has two build numbers associated :

> Builds
>
> - 13E233
> - 13E234

I don't remember of any previous iOS version with multiple builds numbers, so it raised some questions :

- First, why is there two build numbers ? The builds were made successively according to the difference between them, so maybe there are one iPhone and one iPad build.
- What is the difference between these builds ?
- How can I detect which build i'm using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the name of each platform's `ipsw` file, you will see which binaries were build 13E233 or 13E234:

```
iPhone 6s
iPhone8,1_9.3_13E234_Restore.ipsw

iPhone 6s Plus
iPhone8,2_9.3_13E234_Restore.ipsw

iPhone SE
iPhone8,4_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPhone 6
iPhone7,2_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPhone 6 Plus
iPhone7,1_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPhone 5s (CDMA)
iPhone6,2_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPhone 5s (GSM)
iPhone6,1_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPhone 5 (CDMA)
iPhone5,2_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPhone 5 (GSM)
iPhone5,1_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPhone 5c (CDMA)
iPhone5,4_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPhone 5c (GSM)
iPhone5,3_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPhone 4S
iPhone4,1_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Pro 12"
iPad6,7_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Pro 12" (LTE Cellular)
iPad6,8_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Pro 9" model
iPad6,3_9.3_13E234_Restore.ipsw

iPad Pro 9" model (LTE Cellular)
iPad6,4_9.3_13E234_Restore.ipsw

iPad Air 2
iPad5,3_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Air 2 (LTE Cellular)
iPad5,4_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Air (5th generation Cellular)
iPad4,2_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Air (5th generation)
iPad4,1_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Air (5th generation China)
iPad4,3_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad (4th generation CDMA)
iPad3,6_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad (4th generation GSM)
iPad3,5_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad (4th generation)
iPad3,4_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad 3 Wi-Fi (3rd generation)
iPad3,1_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad 3 Wi-Fi + Cellular (GSM)
iPad3,3_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad 3 Wi-Fi + Cellular (CDMA)
iPad3,2_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad 2 Wi-Fi (Rev A)
iPad2,4_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad 2 Wi-Fi
iPad2,1_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad 2 Wi-Fi + 3G (GSM)
iPad2,2_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad 2 Wi-Fi + 3G (CDMA)
iPad2,3_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Mini (CDMA)
iPad2,7_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Mini (GSM)
iPad2,6_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Mini
iPad2,5_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Mini 2 (Cellular)
iPad4,5_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Mini 2
iPad4,4_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Mini 2 (China)
iPad4,6_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Mini 3 (China)
iPad4,9_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Mini 3
iPad4,7_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Mini 3 (Cellular)
iPad4,8_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Mini 4
iPad5,1_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPad Mini 4 (Cellular)
iPad5,2_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPod touch (5th-generation)
iPod5,1_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw

iPod touch (6th-generation)
iPod7,1_9.3_13E233_Restore.ipsw
```

The binaries that were build 13E234 were for the iPhone 6s, 6s Plus, and iPad Pro 9" devices.

Comment: Nice catch, I forgot that the build was included into the ipsw file. I have no idea why there is a difference for these devices, but your answer will surely help to find it ;)